# run multiple task in crontab in the same time without delay

Tags: linux, task, cron, schedule

I have to run task which take time 3 or 5 minut
How to run multiple task in crontab -in same time ?

crontab -e

```
0 13 * * * /etc/rip_first_radio.sh
0 13 * * * /etc/rip_second_radio.sh
0 13 * * * /etc/rip_third_radio.sh
0 13 * * * /etc/rip_fourth_radio.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

your crontab config is correct. But you can add add all into one script and run also.

```
vi main.sh
./etc/rip_first_radio.sh &
./etc/rip_second_radio.sh &
./etc/rip_third_radio.sh &
./etc/rip_fourth_radio.sh &
```

and add main.sh to cron.

```
0 13 * * * ./main.sh
```